# Make classic ASP page restful

Tags: rest, asp-classic

Someone asked me "How do you make a classic ASP page restful?"

1) Is that a valid question?

2) Do they mean to ask how you would connect to a restful service?

3) Do they mean there are web services within the page and they should be made restful?

4) Can this (making restful or calling restful API) be done with classic ASP?

4) If the way I understood it in 2 is correct, what is the best/quickest way to do this: 
 a) by converting it to an ASP.net MVC app ? 
 b) using javascript/jquery ?

Thanks!!

Comment: Do they want you to make a REST API or connect to a 3rd party's REST API? Both are possible in Classic ASP.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly make a call to a restful web service using Classic ASP.  Here's an example which accesses Bing's custom search API.  This gets an xml response but if your service provides a JSON response then this can be modified accordingly.  Also I like to use an xsl layer to parse xml but you can do it in pure asp/vbs if you prefer

```
Option Explicit
    Dim xml, xsl

    Set xml = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    xml.open "POST","https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Web?Query=%27my+query%27&$top=15", false, "myUserId", "MyPassword"
    xml.send 
    Response.ContentType = "application/xml"

    Set xsl = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DomDocument.6.0")
    xsl.load(Server.Mappath("bingsearch.xsl"))

    Response.Write  xml.responseXML.transformNode(xsl)

    Set xsl = Nothing
    Set xml = Nothing
```

Not sure how or if you could make the asp page itself restful thouh